# XNA Game Studio 3 and Visual Studio 2010

Tags: xna, xna-4.0, xna-3.0

I use Visual Studio 2010 and XNA Game Studio 4 for game development. Now I want to test the "XNA Racing Game" (see here: http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/racing_game). I've downloaded the archive, extracted the files, and opend the soulution with Visual Studio. In Visual Studio an error appears - the game was build with XNA Game studio 3, I need to install GS 3. Okay, I've downlaoded GS 3 and I've tried to install it. The problem is now that GS 3 needs Visual Studio 2008. I don't have Visual Studio 2008.

Is is anyway possible to use Visual Studio 2010 with GS 3?

Comment: fyi - there is also a stack exchange dedicated to game development http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download [Visual Studio 2008 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#Visual_Studio_2008_Express_Downloads) which is free and works well with XNA.

Comment: As I said, I don't want to use Visual Studio 2008, because I have already installed Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: The two versions can coexist on a machine without any problems.